# How to redirect to another sub-domain using IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have changed my domain name from (**www.example.com**)
to (**in.example.com**)

the issue is that all old facebook links and campaigns links redirect to the old domain which will show an error due to the change of the domain.

and I am really not good with IIS rules, I have searched on how to make rules to handle this but I could not make it.

all that I need is very simple: if the user open http://www.example.com/Vehicle/all
it should redirect him to 
http://in.example.com/Vehicle/all

if the user visits the direct domain it should not remain on the same original domain: http://www.example.com

Answer (score -1):

You Can do redirection from your cpanel. you will find redirection under Domains section

Comment: This question has nothing to do with cpanel

Comment: the question is about redirection and you can perform redirection from cpanel or iis settings